# What is 'DOC' in terms for Depth of Discharge for SLA batteries?

Tags: batteries, discharge, lead-acid

I'm trying to understand the [spec of a SLA battery](https://www.sunstonepower.com/Solar-Battery-Deep-Cycle-Battery-12v-26ah-AGM-Lead-Acid-Battery-pd6674960.html). There's a chart which is titled "Cycle Life in Relation to Depth of Discharge":

[image]

Can I ask what 'DOC' stands for and the chart is read? How come that line exceeds 100 on the left axis? I presume the left axis represents the percentage of discharge.

Comment: it probably exceeds 100% because the marketing intern who made it thought the arc looked cool

Comment: It seems that DOC = Depth Of Discharge

Comment: @G36 Right. But what about the left axis?

Comment: The left axis is the percentage of discharge. And more than 100% maybe means that the battery was charged above the normal amp-hours capacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOC looks like an erroneous contraction of DOD and SOC ...
DoD = Depth of Discharge
SoC = State of Charge

SoC is equal to 100% when the DoD is 0%, and 0% when the DoD is 100%

Regarding exceeding the 100%:

> It is sometimes possible for a battery DoD to exceed 100%, if the nominal energy capacity was estimated conservatively, or because of actual operating conditions different from the nominal operating conditions.
>   [Source](https://energymag.net/dod-depth-of-discharge/)

(the latter already suggested by @G36).